# append отрабатывает дважды при ready и resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется функция с `.append` внутри. Она вызывается при `.ready` документа и его `.resize`. В результате `.append` срабатывает дважды. 
Можно ли каким-то образом избежать этого?
**Важно:** вызов функции при загрузке страницы и её ресайзе должнен остаться.

```js
function example() {
  var targetBLock = $('.content');
  
  targetBLock.append(' <span class="additional">additional content</span>');
}
example();
$(window).resize(example());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">Some content</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

надо так

```
$(window).resize(example);
```

потому что `example()` - вызов функции